# DDoSing ports, do numbers matter?

Tags: networking, port

I know people typically DDoS port 80, but let's say I DDoS any port besides 80, would surpassing the given port speed of any specified port still cripple someones network? Say I want to DDoS port 45, would that still affect them? I remember hearing somewhere that the port number doesn't matter, as long as the packets surpass the allowed port speed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically if you specified an opening port, it will use for doing tcp syn flood attack, which make a connection to server side so it required the application to respond, which is much powerful.

If you don't know which port is opening (Let's say server is opening port 80 but you choose port 45 to attack), you can't make tcp sync flood because server will not respond you. So you may consider the other way like UDP flood, where UDP is is not port specified, you can attack it from any port, however the "performance vs efficiency" rate is much lesser, because you are pumping traffic to server without waiting acknowledge. This use a lots of computer power and bandwidth.

Why people always pick port 80 because it represent web services, if you are able to surf it from Firefox, you can ddos it (theoretically).